# How to pass input to controller in Yii that does not belong to the Model

Tags: php, yii

I have a user creation form for `User` model (`User extends CActiveRecord`), with some regular fields like username, password or e-mail.

The fields of the form are created in the view like:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'superuser'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'superuser', User::itemAlias('AdminStatus')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'superuser'); ?>
</div>
```

I actually can create users with this form, but now I need to add extra information.

What I need is to add a dropdown with 'City' list (which I would retrieve from DB via Ajax) and send the corresponding `city_id` to the `UserController` to do some stuff and add an extra field to the `User` based on the `city_id`, before saving. So this `city_id` does not belong to the model, I just need it in the controller to do some calculation.

Looks like a simple question, but right now I do not know ho to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to process city_id in controller only? No need to insert into db?

Comment: @kumar_v I am going to processs `city_id` in controller, I will not insert it into db. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Add a class variable in your model.

   `public $city_id;`

Then you can call in view as below

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'city_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'city_id', $urcity_arr; ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'city_id'); ?>
</div>
```

2.You can do with CHTML

But you can access in controller as `$_POST["city_id"];`

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropdownlist('city_id', 'selected value',$urcity_arr); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: as @kumar_v said
Option 2: to add city_id as an attribute to the User Model

```
class User extends CActiveRecord{
public $city_id ;
...
}
```